# Marxism - primary contradiction of capitalism

Tags: marx, marxism, philosophy-of-economics, economics

After writing a long post, i decided to keep only the summary :
I understand that in the marxist framework a mode of production is constituted by :

- the relations of production
- the productive forces

And that the engine of the (r)evolution of the mode of production, and its development is the contradiction between the 2. At some point the relations of production are an obstacle to the development of the productive forces. So my questions are :

- how is it exactly that private property of means of production (the relations of production) and a socialized production (the productive forces) through the development of capitalism and an increasingly large-scale industry, constitute a contradiction, and the main one, in capitalist mode of production ?
- how does that contradiction manifests itself ? Through economic crises, i've also read "the destruction of productive forces during those crises", but how are economic crises manifestations of this contradiction ?
- how, according to marxism, is this supposed to lead to a socialist mode of production ? Taking from Lenin and his book on imperialism, that contradiction is being "solved" by ever-increasing concentration of capital, leading to monopolies in different branches of production, and the merger of branches of production, for example financial capital, being the merger of bank capital and industrial capital. And one can see how one large monopolistic company in one branch can purchase or merge with another monopolistic company of another branch. How is socialism supposed to happen or being brought ?

Thank you

Comment: I wanted you to have this review of Michael Harrington's book, "The Twilight of Capitalism" (1977). It was written at an odd time, and got lost in the "Reagan Revolution" which began in 1981. This is a review in the Hofstra Law Review. It is a good book because it was written at the end of a certain era, however, the paperback was made with poor glue and it may be difficult to find this book even in a good library. https://scholarlycommons.law.hofstra.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1189&context=hlr

Comment: Looks like a series of essay questions one might get from the typical intro phil class.

Answer (score 5):

> how is it exactly that private property of means of production (the
>   relations of production) and a socialized production (the productive
>   forces) through the development of capitalism and an increasingly
>   large-scale industry, constitute a contradiction, and the main one, in
>   capitalist mode of production ?

Well.

If the property of means of production is private, and production is essentially production of commodities, then production is led by **competition**. Competition forces each private producer of commodities to seek to offer their commodities at the lowest price. This in turn makes each producer of commodities seek to systematically increase surplus value, which, barred the primitive and inefficient method of reducing wages and extending labour hours, is only possible through increased productivity of labour, which is only possible through increasing the composition of capital - ie, by improving the means of production so that workers produce more per unit of time.

Problem is, value is a function of labour time. So while the individual producer, when succeeding to increase the productivity of his/her unit of production, makes superprofits as long as the competition remains at an archaic level of productivity, the effect of the increase of productivity, as it spreads among all the productive system (or as it leads the least productive producers into bankrupcy), is to lower the value of each commodity, as it embodies lesser and lesser amounts of human labour.

In philosophical terms, this means that there is a contradiction between **value** and **wealth**; while value is the form of most wealth in a capitalist society, its relation to its substance, wealth, is doublefold:

1. Synchronically, value is proportional to wealth: two coats are the double wealth as one coat, and the value of two coats is the double of the value of one coat;
2. Diachronically, value is proportional only to labour time; doubling the wealth by halving the labour time to produce it doesn't double the value. When you are able to produce two coats in the time you formerly produced only one, wealth is doubled, but value remains the same.

At some point in the development of such a system, increasing the productivity is no longer worth the pain: gains of productivity will no longer result in increased profits. If the proportion between dead labour and live labour in a low-tech environment is 1/1, then profits will expand quite nicely by turning that proportion to 2/1. But when the proportion is already 100/1, increases in it will have very little effect on profits; the system no longer rewards gains of productivity - and has therefore come to be "an obstacle to the development of the productive forces" as you put it.

> how does that contradiction manifests
>   itself ? Through economic crises, i've also read "the destruction of
>   productive forces during those crises", but how are economic crises
>   manifestations of this contradiction ?

Economic crises in capitalism are basically crises of overproduction. As each producer of commodities seeks to offer the lowest possible prices, and to sell the largest possible amount of individual commodities in order to compensate for lower prices, time comes when there are too many commodities in the market, and part of them becomes unsalable. Part of these commodities being productive forces themselves, if they are not sold and subsequently used, they are wasted, which is in itself a form of "destruction of productive forces".

Economic crises tend to unleash political crises, in which further destruction of productive forces may happen, in the form of wars, sabotage, etc.

> how, according to marxism, is this supposed to lead to a socialist
>   mode of production ? Taking from Lenin and his book on imperialism,
>   that contradiction is being "solved" by ever-increasing concentration
>   of capital, leading to monopolies in different branches of production,
>   and the merger of branches of production, for example financial
>   capital, being the merger of bank capital and industrial capital. And
>   one can see how one large monopolistic company in one branch can
>   purchase or merge with another monopolistic company of another branch.
>   How is socialism supposed to happen or being brought ?

The short answer is it doesn't. Socialism is thought to be only possible via a political revolution, which is a deliberate action by human agents. What the development of the capitalist system provide are merely conditions for such a revolution, which may be summarised as,

1. Suppression of scarcity: under previous modes of production, the amount of wealth generated by human labour was always unsufficient to provide a rich, meaningful life for all mankind if it was equitatively divided;
2. Destruction of petty, "idylic" previous relations that tied human beings to their country, province, town or hamlet;
3. Creation of the means for social control of production, via automation of decision making;
4. Creation of a mass of individuals who are denied access to most of the wealth created, although being responsible for the creation of all value, which is thought to provide the "human agents" required for the deliberate action of revolution.

The crises of capitalism, on the other hand, provide the empirical evidence that the system is unable to work smoothly, and that the "fixes" it needs to reboot itself into a new cycle of prosperity are too costly in terms of human lives and suffering to be continuously tolerated for an indeterminate lapse of time; and also the political fractures that may make the deliberate action of revolution **possible**.

Comment: nice long and through answer, pretty satisfying after a first reading (contradiction between wealth and value, the lack of incentive for productivity growth after some point and overproduction).

Let me process it and connect the dots :)

Comment: Thank you. If necessary, I can improve on the above answer.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose @Atif is not quite right in saying "Makers of wealth are not the workers alone (**as Communism think**)". Communism says that wealth is the result of human labor. And that's all. If an entrepreneur works (mentally) he creates wealth as well. But this wealth can by materialized only by physical labor. The philosopher creates wealth by his mental labor, but if his ideas are not shared with other people his wealth remains unuseful for mankind.

The main idea is that the only way to create wealth is physical labor. Making shoes, writing a poem, explaining theory to other listeners - all of this is physical HUMAN labor. And this human labor creates real wealth, useful for other people.

The main difference between a worker and an entrepreneur is the duration of labor. A worker works 8 hours a day and gets a minimal salary, but the entrepreneur works one hour a week and gets much much more income. The main idea of business is that other people work for you. They work harder than you, but get less than you. This is the main point of capitalism and its weak spot.

Hope my English is good enough to explain matters clearly.

Comment: Hello Alex and welcome to PSE. Your English is fine on the whole. I've made a few changes but I do not want to alter your meaning. If any of my changes don't reflect what you want to say, you can edit them out. Only trying to help. Best - Geoffrey

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas, thanks for your changes!

Answer (score 1):

Private property rights is necessary in order to accumulate wealth and thereby concentrate capital. With increasing concentration of capital the workers becomes relatively poorer and according to some interpretations of marxism even absolutely poorer. This happens such an extent that labour cannot reproduce itself, when wages falls below what is necessary eat and drink enough to be able to go to work tomorrow. This reveal an internal inconsistency in the capitalist system because labour is necessary to uphold production in the first place, without labour capital is dead. According to one interpretation it leads to a socialist mode of production through revolution, where the impoverished develop class consciousness and unite to overthrow the system.

Comment: "Private property rights is necessary in order to accumulate wealth and thereby concentrate capital."
>> how so ? Some entity, like the state or any unit of production, collectively owned by workers, could also accumulate wealth. I've read that happened in some communes and/or brigades of production in China after the revolution

"With increasing concentration of capital the workers becomes relatively poorer and according to some interpretations of marxism even absolutely poorer."
>> Then again, how so ? The concentration of capital _could_ imply an increase in so-called "variable capital"

Comment: "This happens such an extent that labour cannot reproduce itself, when wages falls below what is necessary eat and drink enough to be able to go to work tomorrow."

>> While i get that point, i question your premisses, or how you formulated them

Comment: "This reveal an internal inconsistency in the capitalist system because labour is necessary to uphold production in the first place, without labour capital is dead."
>> So i understand that you say the contradiction is that increase in accumulation for a private owner, separated from the workers, tends to drive wages down, to the point that productive forces (the workers) can no longer, or not sufficiently survive. that lack of reproduction of workers/productive forces hinders the development of productive forces (obviously) and as a result of capital itself.

Comment: Thx for the comments @joseph M'Bimbi-Bene the reason I choose to speak about "reproduction" is because it in my opinion something that distinguishes how Marx thought about labor as compared to Neoliberal Economics as is often taught at Universities many places today. "Hence, the price of labor is also equal to the cost of production of labor. But, the costs of production of labor consist of precisely the quantity of means of subsistence necessary to enable the worker to continue working" [marx on labor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labour_power) to quote from Wiki.

Comment: but then, either in a context of monopoly or concurrency, facing a threat of revolution, the owners could increase wages, or modify the "composition of capital" with more variable capital. 

I've heard a few times that's the point of modern social-democrat, with the sole purpose of increasing wages and adding some "social" features to the state. It is often said to be some "tactics" of the bourgeoisie (at least its left side) to prevent the people from rebelling and organizing themselves to make a revolution

Comment: I think that commenting on real world examples opens another discussion, which includes whether Marx was right. I thought your question was about how to interpret Marx, not how world economics works and whether Marx was right. Perhaps I misunderstood you.

Comment: "Some entity, like the state or any unit of production, collectively owned by workers, could also accumulate wealth." No not in theory, in theory it is exactly "collectively owned". Whether you buy that theory and believe it accurately represents the state of affairs in certain countries, self-proclaimed communist, is another story.

Comment: No problem, in fact i think your answers were appropriate and maybe i was mixing the 2 questions : "how to interpret max ?" and "Was that true ?".

In my own questionning and enquiring of marxism, i try, as much as a regular guy can, to consider real world examples. That helps me consolidate my understanding of the works of marx and other marxists, and also i understand it as the whole point of Marxism : a collection of tools to make sense of the world in order to have the leverage to change it.

But I think my purpose might not have been clear from the beginning, even to myself

Comment: Ok, I hold an education in economics so when I try to understand Marx I mostly look for points where he says something different than what I was being taught at University. So my answer might be biased in that way. No neoliberal economist would argue that wage represents "means of subsistence" at least not to my knowledge.

Comment: Oh, and what is being told about labour and its cost in a classical economics course ?
I am a computer programmer, so no background in economics. With a knack for testing, maybe that's while i am sweating the details out of anything i get my hands on.
" No not in theory, in theory it is exactly "collectively owned" "
>> So in theory, if it is collectively owned, there is no accumulation, all the wealth and value that is generated is distributed to workers or used for investment, increase of means of production and public services.
i guess it supposes that the wealth is fully collectivzed

Comment: Well assuming free markets the value of labour equals marginal productivity of labour. Firms maximize profit $\max_L pF(L) - wL$ where $F(L)=Y$ is units produced when using $L$ units of labour and sold at the price $p$ that firms cannot set due to perfect competition, so they take product price as given. In optimum first order condition holds so $ \frac{\partial F(L)}{\partial L} = \frac{w}{p}$ hence marginal productivity must eqaul wage divided by product unit price.

Comment: "Collectively owned" - there can be accumulation but not concentration. Think about schools they are often state owned, if the state is doing good from an economic perspective it can invest it money in a good educational system to the benefit of everyone (I live in Denmark, Universities are free here, you litteraly pay 0).

Comment: Sure one state can do better than another and accumulate more wealth and put it into educational system, but if everyone has equal right to go to school then this does no imply "concentration" of wealth. So the private property rights works as a means of wealth concentration, creating rich and poor. Classconflict is the result.

Comment: I meant "neccessary" in the sense of being a means to and more emphasis on "concentration" than "accumulation". I was imprecise but was aiming to keep it short to set out what I think is the core "logic" in Marx.

Comment: I am reading and crunching everything you said, with what i read, trying to reach a new level of understanding and have new questions.

Anyway i think i understand what you mean when you introduce a difference between accumulation and concentration. 
The first allows to "pay" for non-profit generating activities for examples, while i understand with the second you designate the fact of keeping the profit or surplus value and not spending it. Am i right ?

Comment: Then i feel there is still a difference from my understanding of "concentration", from reading Lenin for example, where it seems to define the act going to ever-increasing scale of production while cleaning concurrence, the process of going from concurrence capitalism to monopolistic capitalism. At least what i understood.

Merging of producers in one branch of production and merging of branches.

I need to chew and digest all that. Anyway thank you your explanations made me see things clearer and gave me new and understandable material to consider

Comment: By "accumulation" I mean we get more wealth per person. So yesterday we had 2 pieces of bread per person today we have 4 and lets say we are 5 persons. So we have become more productive and accumulated more material wealth. However by "concentration" I refer to the distribution of wealth across individuals. Ok, we have more bread yesterday each person had 2 pieces, today we have 4 persons with 2 pieces each and 1 with 12 pieces that still 4 pieces per person but the distribution is uneven there is concentration.

Comment: How can that happen? Only by somehow sort of assigning pieces of bread to specific individuals. Hence bread is treated as belonging to someone. What is that a manifestation of? Private property. To say that someone has 12 pieces of bread is exactly to assign him or her ownership. If property were collective I could not say that, there would just be 20 pieces of bread and 5 people and 4 per person.

Comment: "Some entity, like the state or any unit of production, collectively owned by workers, could also accumulate wealth." Accumulate wealth initially by gathering whats there already, yes. Use that wealth to produce enough to have surplus, after living costs are met, no. No surplus, no accumulation. You see people work only to get pleasure or to avoid pain. There is no other motivator for humans. After brief post-revolution idealism little revolutionary pleasure is left in people to be motivated by revolutionary idealism alone. They ask for their share in whats produced.

Comment: Big difference between private companies and govt owned companies is, govt can force people to work (put them in jail, send them to work-camps/gulags, even torture) so people work to avoid pain, not to get pleasure. Ofcourse this don't work for long. People become de-sensitized. Torturers after a while don't torture enough. A sense of lethargy and unhopefulness spread. Nobody work beyond the bare minimum anymore. Whats produced therefore is barely enough to cover just the basic living costs. There is no surplus, no growth. Compare that with private enterprise...

Comment: ...Entrepreneur get handsome profit, ofcourse he is motivated. Also, he is forced to pay workers because there is no other way to motivate the workers (he cannot torture). Therefore, capitalism is a fairer method than Communism. Its fairer because whats produced go to workers and managers of business (entrepreneurs) more than it do in Communism. However, as long as whats produced do not totally goes to the two groups, that is, some is set aside, system will eventually fail. Faster or slower depending on how much is set aside.

Answer (score -2):

There is only one problem with Capitalism. Its that the equation between supply and demand don't balance.

### Capital Comes From Production

Capitalism favors accumulation of capital (ofcourse). The capital comes from production. A part of production is not consumed, its accumulated in form of capital.

More capital means more production in next cycle. Then even more in next cycle, and so on. This perpetuates because it makes its supporters (capitalists) stronger.

### Capitalists Will Always Out-Produce Non-Capitalists

Politically, capitalist countries will always out-produce non-capitalist countries and therefore beat them in all material wars and gathering of human talent. Economically, capitalist companies will always beat non-capitalist companies because of sheer production.

### Tried And Failed Methods Against Capitalism

Different techniques have been tried to beat capitalists in production. British Mercantilism failed, inspite of its control on markets (colonies) it just couldn't out-produce america (note that pricing is a derivative here, not a primary, because if you can out-produce you can always offer low price). German and Italian Fascism failed because of their focus on quality. Soviet Communism failed too, but why? Soviet State itself can easily out-produce private companies in capitalist countries and Soviet Union was a very large country, in population, area, raw materials, everything needed for production.

Note that other communisms didn't fail. Cuba survived.

### Why Did Soviet Communism Failed

Soviet Communism failed because it was focused on accumulation of capital. Soviet State invested heavily in production. Be it factories or power plants.

Soviet Communism not only failed, it failed faster than Capitalism.

The reason Soviet Communism failed is that it don't balance the equation between supply and demand. There was a lot of supply, but there wasn't enough demand. You know demand as an economic term means not only there is desire to buy there must also be money available to buy.

Soviet Communism didn't pay the workers and the managers enough. They were paid just enough to get by, not get anything comfortable, yet alone even any minor luxury in life.

Lots of stuff was produced and stored and ruined in godowns.

This ofcourse leads to a regressive cycle. In next cycle less stuff is produced because the state bureaucracy see little demand last year. This goes on for a while till everybody got fed up and basically resigned from communism ideal.

### Why Would Capitalism Fail

The right way ofcourse is to produce what people desire. Things of utility and quality. Capitalist countries are great in this. They not only out-produce in quantity, they also out-produce in quality and in whats needed and wanted by consumers. This is, however, where goodness of Capitalism ends.

You see Capitalism to be capitalism has to forever accumulate capital. It cannot afford distributing everything that is produced to workers and managers. Its death of capitalism if that ever happen. Some must be saved for next cycle. This is the poison of Capitalism.

Karl Marx was half right ofcourse. Production should be distributed to workers and supervisors. But thats only half of what should happen. The other half is, it should be distributed to entrepreneurs (managers of business), or you would soon have no wealth to distribute.

Makers of wealth is not workers alone (as Communism think). Makers of wealth is not entrepreneurs alone (as Capitalism think). They are both. All the surplus thats left after costs of production, and the costs includes living costs for workers such as rent, food, medical etc, must be distributed to both workers and entrepreneurs (managers).

### Why Did Cuba Survive

Cuba didnt go on path of extreme production. It never focused on accumulation of  capital. Whatever is produced is more or less consumed.

Cuba distributed whatever is produced more or less evenly. But its not the reason why it survived. You see even Feudalism survive.

### The Equation Must Be Balanced, Equal Distribution Or Not

Whats produced don't have to be distributed evenly. The distribution can be very lop-sided. System will still survive. The only requirement is, nothing is kept aside. Everything thats produced is consumed by *someone*.

See this is why capitalist countries thrive in wars. They produce more and consume less, and still survive. Its because a lot thats produced is just destroyed.

As long as the equation between supply and demand, which is another way of saying production and consumption, is balanced, system survive. It don't thrive though. You cannot have it both ways. Either you have a steady state or a dynamic state.

Comment: Capital itself doesn't produce more capital, you'd still need workers/energy to produce more capital. Having more capital means you can hire more people, directly via employment or indirectly by buying goods and services that they produce, but that supply is still limited. Capitalism far too often treats it's supply chain as "alien" while colonies and "marxist-leninist" states are forced to manage them as well. But just because one pretends they aren't there and not in a situation of problem doesn't mean that's actually the case.

Comment: Nobody (except you) said that capital itself produce more capital. Energy in the sense you said do not replace workers, so dont put a slash between workers and energy. Workers supply is limited as sea water is limited. Still no shortage especially when you consider you can always train / educate them to be more productive. The point of my answer is, its accumulation thats the problem, be it in the form of capital or interest. Whatever is produced must all be consumed otherwise you have clogs in arteries that soon kill the organism.

Comment: I'm tempted to give you a thumbs up for the laughs this answer generated.  Not enough demand? The people living there didn't know that. https://englishrussia.com/2017/04/14/lines-in-soviet-union/

Comment: Economic term: demand is more than just desire to have. Its mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Atif "More capital means more production in next cycle." How else am I supposed to read that? The point is that for the creation of a physical good you'd need a physical energy source which limits your growth. Also no the pool of workers is not endless you've got work that needs to be done to sustain society itself, food, logistics, healthcare, social services etc. if you'd hire every available worker for your car company society would starve. Maybe not a 1st world society as they'd have enough capital left to buy food elsewhere, but the 3rd world country supplying the workers would.

Comment: Cancer dont have to spread to each and every cell of your body to kill you. One in thousand would do. Before that, at one in 25 thousand level you will stop functioning as a healthy member of society. More capital is only made if its calculated that it would be profitable i.e. produce more and enough more. Nobody is saying that all production goes to become capital or even whats left after costs. The whole point of the answer is, as long as there is _some_ production set aside i.e. not consumed you have a problem. Your equation is not balanced.

Comment: Communism failed faster than Capitalism because it distribute production to workers and managers even less than Capitalism do. Its because govt can force people to work whereas private companies must pay. Still, Capitalism is bound to fail precisely because it do not consume all that it produce. By its very nature, Capitalism accumulate production to make more and more capital. A little force has little effect, a large force has large effect. Its a matter of degree, not kind. Both Capitalism and Communism are bound to fail. See how real wages fall in america while cost of living rise.

Comment: @Atif But this equalized balance only makes sense from the perspective of a merchant/producer who continuously wants to sell products. But the goal of the individual and society is not an equalized balance but self-determination. Like there is an amount of labor that is necessary to sustain the status quo. If you or your group produces enough in 24h to survive 24 hours you're enslaved by survival if you produce less you'll starve if you produce more you'll have a surplus to enjoy or reinvest. If someone else takes that surplus they can enjoy and reinvest while you starve.

Comment: @Atif Though if you could manage to industrialize and ramp up production so that no one starves you'd have gained freedom for all members of society. Whereas if it keeps accumulating with a person or group to exclusion of the rest, then this person or group gets to say how that surplus is spend. So those who don't have either need to hope for a benevolent dictator or need to find ways to sell those who have surplus stuff they need or that that is getting them more stuff in order to get a share of the stuff themselves.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141937/discussion-between-haxor789-and-atif).